# Reference version variable in gradle plugin DSL?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have following file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.10'
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M7'
    }
...

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.2.10"
```

I would like to use `kotlinVersion` from `ext` block inside `plugins` declaration. How I can achieve that?

When I try to do it directly I get:
`argument list must be exactly 1 literal non empty string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `pluginManagement` block.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_version_management

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference variable in Plugin DSL,

[Plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins) reference below:

> Where **«plugin version» and «plugin id» must be constant, literal,**
>   **strings** and the apply statement with a boolean can be used to disable
>   the default behavior of applying the plugin immediately (e.g. you want
>   to apply it only in subprojects). No other statements are allowed;
>   their presence will cause a compilation error.